# Slow CSS3 animation flickers in Firefox

Tags: firefox, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I want to zoom slowly into an image. My [idea](http://jsfiddle.net/Qkpg6/1/) works very nice in webkit but not in Firefox. 
Does someone know why or how to make it better?

Comment: The effect is reliant on JavaScript, so there's no reason to use CSS3 transforms that I can see, other than the performance gain. But, because the effect takes *20 seconds*, you could do the exact same thing with JavaScript without `transform`, and have it almost as fast, but working in *all browsers*. Something to bear in mind if it's not possible to improve this in Firefox.

Comment: The title is misleading: this is not about [CSS3 animations](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paul Rouget (Mozilla) says it's a bug: http://twitter.com/#!/paulrouget/status/80204726054043648

Bugreport: 
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=663776

**Update:** To keep this up to date. The bugreport is now fixed:

> Verified fixed on FF 20b5 on Windows 7 and Mac OS 10.8

Answer (score 1):

Firefox Opera don't support css3 Animation

test: http://modernizr.github.com/Modernizr/test/index.html

Comment: Firefox 5 (currently beta) does - http://www.css3.info/css3-animations-support-in-firefox-5-beta/
and Opera 10.5 does as well - http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto23/css/transitions/

Comment: Mozilla looks at this as a bug: https://twitter.com/#!/paulrouget/status/80204726054043648

Comment: Are you kidding me? This *doesn't use* animation, it uses `transform` [http://caniuse.com/transforms2d](http://caniuse.com/transforms2d) and `transition` [http://caniuse.com/#search=transition](http://caniuse.com/#search=transition), both of which work in Firefox 4.